# CRM 2016 Erratic Behaviour of RetrieveMultiple Plugin on ActivityPointer entity

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to create a retrievemultiple plugin on the activitypointer entity to filter out all Email activities where duration = 999 days. See code below

```
if (objQueryExpression1.EntityName == "activitypointer")
                        {

                            FilterExpression activityFilter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And)
                            {
                                Conditions =
                                            {
                                                new ConditionExpression("actualdurationminutes", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, 1438560)
                                            }
                            };
                            //objQueryExpression1.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("actualdurationminutes", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, 1438560));
                            objQueryExpression1.Criteria.AddFilter(activityFilter);
                        }


                        context.InputParameters["Query"] = objQueryExpression1;
```

when I register the plugin on retrievemultiple of activitypointer entity, the plugin works fine in 'Advanced Find' mode and in the 'Social Tab' of the related 'Application' entity. However, if I go to the 'Activity Associated View' of the 'Application Entity', it shows me all the activities (including activities with duration=999 days). 
Similarly, if  I go to the contact record (Applicant on the Application), it shows me all activities (including activities with duration=999 days).

Not sure why the retrievemultiple is working in some instance and not in the other.

Answer (score 0):

This won’t work because CRM uses [Rollup message](https://rajeevpentyala.com/tag/activities-associated-view/) instead of RetrieveMultiple in this case.

Rollup message is not available to register in PRT as such.

However there is [unsupported way](http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2010/01/handling-rollup-message-with-plugins-in.html?m=1#!) to expose this Rollup message in PRT.